# Combining two cells in loop VBA (Excel)

Tags: excel, vba, cell

I am trying to combine two cells like this:

Lets say that cell 1 is 123 and cell 2 is 321
Then I want cell 3 to look like this:
123 (321)

So if this was in excel and I wanted to do it with two cells, I would just do it like this:

```
=E2&"("&F2&")"
```

But in VBA, I'm actually trying to do it with a loop. So that the i value is the row, and the column is constant.

I've tried to do it like this:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "='Nye_Virksomheder'!R & i & C2 & ""(""&'Nye_Virksomheder'!R & i & C4&"")"""
```

So "Nye_Virksomheder" is the sheet that i am taking the data from.

But I keep getting an error. Not sure what is wrong. Anyone that is able to figure it out?

Kind regards,
Zebraboard

Comment: Do you still need the formula or just the value is fine?

Comment: The problem is that `& i &`  falls within the quotes. Variables (and operators) belong outside quotes. Actually your quotes are off in several places.

Comment: Hey Raymond, not 100% sure what you mean, but I need the value to be put into the new cell.

Comment: Hey BigBen, I understand, but still not sure how to fix this correctly :(

Comment: You don't need a loop to do this either btw. But I think `"='Nye_Virksomheder'!R" & i & "C2 & ""("" & 'Nye_Virksomheder'!R" & i & "C4 &"")"""`.

Comment: @Zebraboard If you just want the value, try `ActiveCell.Value = Worksheets("Nye_Virksomheder").Cells(i,2).Value & "(" & Worksheets("Nye_Virksomheder").Cells(i,4).Value & ")"`.

Comment: Thank you soo much Bigben. That worked. Also thanks to you Raymond!!

Comment: Not sure how I give you credit because its a comment :(

Comment: @Zebraboard You can accept BigBen's answer as the credit!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several issues with quotes.

```
"='Nye_Virksomheder'!R" & i & "C2 & ""("" & 'Nye_Virksomheder'!R" & i & "C4 &"")"""
```

Note that you don't actually need a loop to write a formula with an increasing row. You can write the formula to the entire range in one go (keeping the row as a relative reference).